# Keep in cells only the first two words with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to keep in the column only the two first words of a cell in a dataframe.

For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["I'm learning Python", "I don't have money"])
```

I would like that the results in the column have the following output:

```
"I'm learning" ; "I don't"
```

After that, if possible I would like to add '*' between each word. So would be like:

```
 "*I'm* *learning*" ; "*I* *don't*"
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with `str.replace`:

```
df[0].str.replace(r'(\S+)\s(\S+).*', r'*\1* *\2*', regex=True)
```

output:

```
0    *I'm* *learning*
1         *I* *don't*
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

As a new column:

```
df['new'] = df[0].str.replace(r'(\S+)\s(\S+).*', r'*\1* *\2*', regex=True)
```

output:

```
                     0               new
0  I'm learning Python  *I'm* *learning*
1   I don't have money       *I* *don't*
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the solution is not working with my database, it didn't change anything. 
I'm getting the following output:  RESOURCE OIL AND IND instead of *RESOURCE* *OIL*

Comment: Do you **assign** the output? Or do you have maybe non standard spaces?

Comment: well the names have different lengths, but the are standard spaces like " ".